AWS SecretsManager with Name not working, but ARN works
I have a secret created with the following ARN and name:

Secret Name: /abc/region/env/def/ghi
Secret ARN: arn:aws:secretsmanager:<region>:<account>:secret:/abc/region/env/def/ghi-atBc1Q


Note the suffix at the end of ARN was added by AWS itself

When I run the following command it works (using ARN):
$ aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id arn:aws:secretsmanager:<region>:<account>:secret:/abc/region/env/def/ghi-atBc1Q | jq -r '.SecretString'
mysecretstring

Now if I run the same command but instead of specifying ARN I specify secret name it fails:
$ aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id /abc/region/env/def/ghi | jq -r '.SecretString'
An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the GetSecretValue operation: Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret.

The code samples in the SecretsManager screen for this secret itself recommend using the secret name instead of ARN. Why isn't it working any clues? Not finding anything useful in the sea of docs from AWS.
